# display logged in user details from in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

view controller

```
<?php

class Site extends CI_Controller {
    function homePage() {
        $this->load->view('homePage');
    }

    function getValues($username) {
        $this->load->model('customer_model');
        $data['results']=$this->customer_model->getOne($username);
        $this->load->view('view_db',$data);
    }
}
```

I wanna display the logged in user details from database to a page. where the user logs in and it directs to home page and in that , there is link which directs to view the users details according to my design..

view Controller of login

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {
    function index() {
        //loads the main page to be displaye din the page
        $this->load->view('login_form');
    }

    function validate_credentials() {
        $this->load->model('customer_model');
        $query = $this->customer_model->validate();

        if ($query) {//if the user credidential is validated 
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );

            //retrieving the session data
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('site/homePage');
        } else {
            $this->index();
    }
}
```

the model view--- i have mentioned only getting a specific user

```
function getOne($username){
    $query=$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username = $username');
    //$this->db->select('*');
    //$query= $this->db->get('customer');
    return $query->result();
}
```

and the view.. where now i just wanna retrieve the value and check later i can improve the interface ;)

```
<?php
//print_r($results);

foreach($results as $row) {
    echo $row->id;
    echo $row->last_name;
    echo "<br/>";
}

?>
```

i know it should be done through a session .. but how to do it?

Comment: I am pretty confused by your question. In the view you want to retrieve the the `username` and `is_logged_in` keys from the session? Have you got any errors? Or are you just trying to check if the user is `is_logged_in`?

Comment: nope..the user logged in details...like when the user registers he gives certain informations right... those detials sud be retrieved and displayed after logging in and when he clicks his user profile.

Comment: am just trying to check that wther user has logged in while logging time.. and in the view i wanna retireve the username firstname email address...somthing like that...

Comment: Ok so when they visit the home pages you want to see if they have logged in or not? If they have not then redirect them to the login page, and if they have logged in then get their account information?

Comment: noo..once they log in ..they will be directed to home page... then when they click a button in homepage they sud be directed to another page where the user will be able see his personal information.. this personal information will be saved in database already.. where they give all details during registering an account.. .. so the particular users information sud be displayed wen he logs in and then click that view profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so when this person who is now logged in clicks on the link that brings them to the `getValues()` method. You can just do a check to see if they are logged in, then if they are retrieve their information based on the sessions `username` key.

```
function getValues(){

    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
        $username = $this->session->userdata('username'); 
        //Get your db results
        $this->load->model('customer_model');
        $data['results']=$this->customer_model->getOne($username);
        $this->load->view('view_db',$data);

    } else{
        //What you want to happen when they are not logged in. 

    }
```

Does that make sense?